Flutter: Prevent Valuenotifier from being removed on the web after a user refreshes it
If the user refreshes his browser while using the web version, all ValueNotifires will disappear, but if, for example, sharedpreferences or other local databases are used, this problem does not exist.
What is the solution so that the ValueNotifires are not cleared?
For information, I use flutter-go-router
Flutter Sdk: 3.22.1
Dart Sdk: 3.4.1

Sharedprefs and other local databases use disk storage, which is why you need to await SharedPreferences.getInstance() before using it. ValueNotifiers are in memory only. You will need to store your ValueNotifier contents somewhere persistent then repopulate them on app or widget load.
Here is a widget that uses a ValueNotifier to store the count variable. This widget will rebuild as needed by changing this value without needing to if (mounted) setState(() {}). It pulls the data from SharedPreferences on widget load and saves the count to disk as the user modifies the value.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class CountWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const CountWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<CountWidget> createState() => _CountWidgetState();
}

class _CountWidgetState extends State<CountWidget> {
  final ValueNotifier<int> _count = ValueNotifier<int>(0);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _count.addListener(
      () => setState(() {}),
    );
    _initializeCount();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _count.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text(_count.toString()),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: _incrementCount,
          child: const Text('Press me'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Future<void> _initializeCount() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final storedCount = prefs.getInt('count_key');
    if (storedCount != null) {
      _count.value = storedCount;
    }
  }

  Future<void> _incrementCount() async {
    _count.value = _count.value + 1;
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setInt('count_key', _count.value);
  }
}

